# Data items from a folder is not displayed in jsp using scriptlets

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

this is my jsp's jstl code.

```
<%@page import="java.io.File" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>`enter code here`
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <form>
    <%
      String path = "C:/NetBeansProjects/prac/build/web/data";

  String files;
  File folder = new File(path);
  File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); 

  for(int i = 0;i < listOfFiles.length;i++) 
  {

   if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) 
   {
   files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
       if (files.endsWith(".mp3"))
       {
          System.out.println(files);
        }
     }
  }
    %>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

what if I want to display it through servlet then where to write this code? 
Here I cannot display any of the output. And I also have no error.

Comment: Dont write Java code in JSP its not good practice add this code in Java file make list and pass it to JSp page

Comment: okay thanks. but I was not knowing this. :/. Anyways thanks.. it solved me.

Comment: @SubodhJoshi  what if I want to write in servlet?  and I want to make this as link so if I click on them I can play the songs.

Comment: @user2243471 Putting business logic in Servlet never be a good idea . Servlet is work as a Controller. So each request process by Servlet .

Comment: @SubodhJoshi so what to do now?

Comment: Are you developing a new Project or You have a well establish project?

Comment: half of my proj is developed. but this is the main part to select and play the desired audio files. You can suggest me both of your suggestions. I mean this is my own peoject that I have been developing.